# Cannot use db2move from another directory

Tags: linux, macos, db2

I am trying to use `db2move` to import table that is in another directory. In fact I am making a script to do some things and one step is import tables that is in `/Dumps/test/` folder.

If I go to `/Dumps/test` and call `db2move <DB> import` it works fine but I need to call it two folder back.

Ps.: I am using Linux and MAC

How can I do it?

Comment: You cannot: `db2move` looks for the file list and data files in the current directory.

Comment: change the working directory in your script before invoking db2move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do it is changing the current directory.